# Use standard Window to draw with wxWidgets into?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wxwidgets

Following situation: I have a DLL that bases on wxWidgets and can generate a lot of wxWidgets-GUI-elements. Next there is a calling application which makes use of this DLL and its functions.

This calling instance e.g. can be a C#-application with absolutely no wxWidgets bindings. It comes with an own user interface that includes a wf:Panel.

In a next step the C#-application retrieves the windows HWND of this wf:Panel and hands it over to my DLL. This HWND is a valid, native Windows handle.

My question: what do I have to do within my DLL exactly in order to use this HWND / this wf:Panel as an wxWidgets-element where I can place standard GUI-elements like a wxButton/wxSizers and so on?

I found a function SetHWND() but this does not seem to do the trick as it expects a wxWidgets-generated panel while I have a panel that is generated in my C#-application...

Comment: @HansPassant this function returns only wxWidgets-objects - but as my panel has been created in C#, this function returns NULL for me

Comment: you can search the window either by id, label or name, according to the documentation. Can you ask the developers the main app to give you such info? Then all you need to do is call `wxWindiw *parent = FindWindowByXXX(); if( parent) new wxButton( parent, ... );`. It looks like in 3.1.3 there is FindItemByHWND(), but I can't find its documentation in the docs for master. And its not static.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wxNativeContainerWindow` to create a `wxTopLevelWindow` representing the foreign `HWND` you're given and then use it as the parent for all your other windows.

Comment: wouldn't it create another window on top of the C# one? Maybe there is a possibility to make `static wxWindow::FindWindowByHWND()`?

Comment: No, `wxNativeContainerWindow` represents the existing window and doesn't create a new one.

Comment: OK, this does not work when the HWND comes from a C#/WPF application. Although the HWND is valid, wxWidgets can not use it as parent. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "can not"? What happens?